# Stray /377 in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm using Xcode to do some C++ programming and all of a sudden I am receiving a "Stray /377 in program error"

I think is possibly because I recently started using a non-Apple wireless keyboard and I possibly put in some kind of weird key combination that created a nonvisible key.

I tried changing the encoding of the .cpp file to UTF-8, but then when I reopen the file in Xcode it comes out in Chinese.

My project is very large, so it’s not feasible to post the code for the project.

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6 on [Mac OS X v10.6.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard).

I tried opening the project in Xcode 3.1.6 and got the same error.

Comment: It may be the byte-ordering mask of UTF-16, the `U+FEFF`.

Comment: [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) AKA ***byte order mark***. *"In UTF-16, a BOM (U+FEFF) may be placed as the first character of a file or character stream to indicate the endianness (byte order) of all the 16-bit code unit of the file or stream. ... If the 16-bit units use little-endian order ("UTF-16LE"), the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence FF FE"*

Comment: @minmaxavg: I think that is a good guess. The very first byte is probably 0xFF (octal 377. Decimal 255).

Comment: Re *"My project is very large, so it’s not feasible to post the code"*: That is what [MREs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) are for.

Comment: This question is severely underspecified. Neither the source code, nor the ***actual*** error message (only part of probably ***more than one*** error message) is provided. We are left trying to guess what it could be. I am voting to close it.

Comment: But the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 9 years ago"*

Comment: \377 in the beginning of the file is a signature for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) BOM ([UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) (little-endian)) induced errors. (The full error would be the doublet "“stray \377 … stray \376”"). The canonical question may be *[How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/how-should-i-use-gs-finput-charset-compiler-option-correctly-in-order-to-com)*. Or some of its "Linked" questions (RH side).

Answer (score 5):

"377" is octal for "255", or an 8-bit "-1".

Do you have one of those anywhere?

I believe XCode has a hex editor: just look for "0xff" somewhere in your recent source changes.

Answer (score 3):

Octal `377` is decimal `255`. It has no meaning in UTF-8, means a "latin small letter y with diaeresis" in ISO-8859-1. I think its presence in the file is probably a sign that it does not belong and can be removed without further consequences. If you agree, you can try removing all them in your entire tree like this:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i~ 's/\o377//g' {} \;
```

The `-i~` asks `sed` to make a backup copy of the files that it changes, in case you need the originals back -- or want to compare the changes with `diff(1)`.