# Stray in library file

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, gcc4.8

I am building a project. The build is blocked because of stray lines in a library file.

```
/datablock/libcosmosis.so:72:1: error: stray ‘\377’ in program
```

What could cause stray lines in a library file? The library being used here was built early in the same build process. I am using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025320/stray-377-in-xcode

Comment: A preprocessor macro is one thing.

Comment: Stray characters usually signal a wrong encoding or some formatting junk inserted here and there (or perhaps some macro messing around). Try to save the file in ASCII format and trim out the weird characters

Comment: Looks like GCC is treating that file as a source file instead of a library. Post your GCC command line.

Comment: @larsmans gcc command,
`gcc -O3 -g -fPIC -I/media/OSS/lcdm/code/cosmosis/  -std=c99 -shared -x c -o example_c_module.so example_c_module.c /media/OSS/lcdm/code/cosmosis//cosmosis/datablock/libcosmosis.so
/media/OSS/lcdm/code/cosmosis//cosmosis/datablock/libcosmosis.so:1:1: error: stray â<80><98>\177â<80><99> in program`

Comment: @pd33p0k well there it is. you are not linking the .so but tryijg to compile. read a tutorial on the basic usage of GCC.

Comment: I removed `/media/OSS/lcdm/code/cosmosis//cosmosis/datablock/libcosmosis.so` from the above command and it works fine. Now I will have to check why my Make is generating such strange commands with lib*.so as source files. Thanks.

Comment: \377 in the beginning of the file is a signature for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) BOM ([UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) (little-endian)) induced errors. (The full error would be the doublet "“stray \377 … stray \376”"). The canonical question  may be *[How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/how-should-i-use-gs-finput-charset-compiler-option-correctly-in-order-to-com)*.

Comment: A signature for an actual binary file ([ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) may be 177 in the beginning of the file (octal.  "stray \177"  (0x7F). The next three bytes are ASCII "E, "L", and "F".